# Ubuntu update broke bootloader

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04

Today my Ubuntu installation asked for a partial update. I saw that it tried to update grub2, and delete one old component, but that didn't seem to be too troublesome. Anyway, after the update completed it asked for a reboot and now it automatically boots to my secundary Windows installation instead of my Ubuntu installation.

Does someone know if I can easily recover GRUB2 so I can boot back to Ubuntu? I really really need to get to work right now...

Comment: It really screwed up my system. Any means of recovery fails. It seems to be related to the UEFI support. Suddenly my boot says it can't load GRUB because the security settings don't allow it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just bit me too (Lenovo X1 Carbon 2015 model).  I managed to get around it by disabling secure boot in the BIOS

Comment: Setting things to legacy boot seems to fix things for me too right now, Thanks. :) Still, it's pretty sad that a simple upgrade can bork my laptop like this.